# Reducing Javascript array into a map and removing duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I am sure there is a clean way to do this, but I have no idea how to do it.  I want to pluck a column out such that I am only returning the first occurrence of a value, but I want to keep the key that went with it.

I have a dataset that I want reduced.  I want to pluck out the 'precip'.

Say I have this:

```
[
  "2019-01-01" => {"temp" : "cold", "season" : "winter", "precip" : "snow"},
  "2019-02-01" => {"temp" : "cold", "season" : "winter", "precip" : "none"},
  "2019-03-01" => {"temp" : "mild", "season" : "spring", "precip" : "rain"},
  "2019-04-01" => {"temp" : "mild", "season" : "spring", "precip" : "none"},
  "2019-05-01" => {"temp" : "warm", "season" : "spring", "precip" : "rain"},
  "2019-06-01" => {"temp" : "warm", "season" : "summer", "precip" : "hail"},
  "2019-07-01" => {"temp" : "hot", "season" : "summer", "precip" : "none"}
]
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
[
  "2019-01-01" => "snow",
  "2019-02-01" => "none",
  "2019-03-01" => "rain",
  "2019-06-01" => "hail"
]
```

I would think that Array.map has something to do with this, but I don't know how to return the key/value pair instead of just a value (i.e. `map(function(d) { return d.precip })`  )

What is the smooth way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with map? an array or a `Map`?

Comment: Note that it's hard to tell exactly what you are working with since the syntax is invalid. Now have 2 answers both making different assumptions

Comment: I apologize.  In the title, I was referring to a Map (object).  In the text, I was referencing the array map function.

Comment: please add a valid data structure/type for data and result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and take only the first item with the same key.

```js
function getFirstPrecip(data) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, o) => {
            var [[k, { precip }]] = Object.entries(o);
            return m.has(precip) ? m : m.set(precip, k);
        }, new Map),
        ([k, v]) => ({ [v]: k })
    ));
}

var data = [{ "2019-01-01": { temp: "cold", season: "winter", precip: "snow" } }, { "2019-02-01": { temp: "cold", season: "winter", precip: "none" } }, { "2019-03-01": { temp: "mild", season: "spring", precip: "rain" } }, { "2019-04-01": { temp: "mild", season: "spring", precip: "none" } }, { "2019-05-01": { temp: "warm", season: "spring", precip: "rain" } }, { "2019-06-01": { temp: "warm", season: "summer", precip: "hail" } }, { "2019-07-01": { temp: "hot", season: "summer", precip: "none" } }];

console.log(getFirstPrecip(data));
```

Comment: So I'm trying to get this to work with my code, and am having trouble.  I noticed you have a comma after the `var data` declaration, and then go straight into the code.  How would you change it if this code were in a function, and `data` was an array passed as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the keys for the main object, and create a new object that will use those keys and assign the `precip` attribute value as value for the new `key=>value` pair:

```js
var dates = {
  "2019-01-01" : {"temp" : "cold", "season" : "winter", "precip" : "snow"},
  "2019-02-01" : {"temp" : "cold", "season" : "winter", "precip" : "none"},
  "2019-03-01" : {"temp" : "mild", "season" : "spring", "precip" : "rain"},
  "2019-04-01" : {"temp" : "mild", "season" : "spring", "precip" : "none"},
  "2019-05-01" : {"temp" : "warm", "season" : "spring", "precip" : "rain"},
  "2019-06-01" : {"temp" : "warm", "season" : "summer", "precip" : "hail"},
  "2019-07-01" : {"temp" : "hot", "season" : "summer", "precip" : "none"}
};
var result = Object.keys(dates).reduce((k,d) => {return [...k, {[d]:dates[d].precip}]}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I have a question that makes this a bit harder.  What if the date was inside the key-value pairs (say `"date":"2019-07-01"`), and I wanted the result to be the same?  So how would I pull the date out of the key-value pair and make it the new key for the returned dataset?

Comment: You'd just have to replace the `{[d]:dates[d].precip}`, where `d` is the date key, for `{[dates[d].date]:dates[d].precip}` to use the new key extracted from another value in the object.

Comment: You can try the above code by replaceing `[d]` for `[dates[d].temp]` to get a `key:value` pair from the temp and precip values in your object.